# How to find the shortest path between specified vertices

Tags: graphs-and-networks, list-manipulation

I am fairly new to Mathematica. I currently have a large weighted undirected graph representing a road network and I have a number of locations that I want to find the shortest paths between. There are currently two options with the FindShortestPath function; vertex *a* to *b* or vertex *a* to *ALL*.

Is there away to find the shortest path from *a* to *a, c, d, e* and *f* all in one instead of running the query each time for every shortest path.

I also am trying to find a way to table the GraphDistance for each shortest path.

I have a large graph with 1000s of vertices so scrolling through the GraphDistanceMatrix is a nightmare.

Cheers!

Comment: The docs mention the syntax needed to generate a `ShortestPathFunction[]` from your graph. Have you tried that already?

Comment: Hey @J.M. I have tired the spf but still can only input one at a time. I am not sure how to write it into a script so I can input a whole list of vertices at once. Maybe the better way to word the question is: Which vertex (from a specific list of vertices, not all in the graph) {b, c, d, e, f} is closer to vertex _a_ ?

Comment: If `spf = FindShortestPath[graph, All, All]`, then do `spf[a, #] & /@  {b, c, d, e, f}`... right?

Comment: I do not understand your question.  You said yourself that it is possible to find shortest paths from `a` to `All`. Is this not what you want—find shortest paths from one vertex to all others?  Note that finding it only to *some* (instead of all) others will not help with performance: the algorithm works in such a way that it discovers all shortest paths starting from one vertex.

Comment: If you need only the distance (but not the exact path) from *some* vertices to *some* others (but not the full graph distance matrix), try `IGDistanceMatrix` form `IGraph/M`. In these cases it can significantly outperform `GraphDistanceMatrix`.

Comment: Great!, Yes that works. Thanks for your help @J.M.